# Paying Italian Taxes

Tags: residency, italy

I am working in Italy from September 2016. - May 2017.  From September 2016 to December 2016 I will be in Italy less than 183 days, as I will be making visit to the UK.  From January 2017-May 2017 again I will be in Italy less than 183 days.  I want to remain uk resident and someone said today that as I will be in Italy for over 183 days in 12 month period(although it goes over 2 tax years)this makes me Italian resident?
Can anyone help?

Comment: If Italy decides that you are a resident for tax purposes, that doesn't necessarily mean that you lose your status as a UK resident, for tax or other purposes.  However, to address your concerns we need to know specifically what UK status you are trying to protect.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, my concern is that if I become Italian tax resident then I have to pay Italian taxes on my worldwide income for the year.  So I need to confirm if the 183 day rule runs from Italian tax year Jan to December or can it cross over 2 tax years I.e September to may

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there will be a double taxation treaty of Italy with the UK and if you did register correctly with the anagrafe in Italy (immediately after arriving in September 2016) and un-registered upon leaving then you should only pay taxes to Italy for that period. In the case that you only have one job in Italy and get paid directly from Italy, and that you don't have any incomes from interest, dividends or rent somewhere else, my belief is that you don't even have to make a tax declaration, but elsewise you should. This is a tricky thing and if you want to do things the correct way (which can be hard in Italy) you most likely require the help of a tax consultant. Try contacting a few until you get one who speaks sufficient English (unless your Italian is fluent) and seems trustworthy. By trustworthy I mean that your situation is likely complex and I would not trust a guy who tells me "I know how to do this, no problem" from the start, they will likely need to look stuff up themselves if they do it right. But then again, doing this right is certainly not the easiest of ways.